# Send Javascript Variable to HTML Img Source

Tags: javascript, html, image, elementor

I am utilizing a piece of JavaScript code to change image sources on a WordPress website (leveraging the Elementor editor), which is based on a button click updating the URL with a specific string. For example, this process would yield the following:

**Before Click:** [www.website.com/acoolpage/](http://www.website.com/acoolpage/)

**After Click:** [www.website.com/acoolpage/?picture=ws10m](http://www.website.com/acoolpage/?picture=ws10m)

This HTML constructor creates the dimension of the image, but **does not update** the image source with the desired result after the button click, when the URL switches to `www.website.com/acoolpage/?picture=ws10m`. What additional steps and/or edits are required? Thanks!

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const pictureParam = urlParams.get('?picture=')

const pictureUrl =
  switch (pictureParam) {
    case 'ws10m':
      return 'https://www.website.com/graphics/image_ws10m.png'
      break

    default:
      return 'https://www.website.com/graphics/image_t2m.png'
      break
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <img src=pictureURL alt="Test" width="1920" height="1080">
</body>
```

Comment: `const pictureParam = urlParams.get('picture')`

Comment: `urlParams.get()` doesn't require you to include the `?` and `=`. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get)

Comment: Also switch does not return anything and you are not assigning the url to the image srd anywhere

Comment: Your code throws an error (as seen above). Does this occur in your live situation?

Comment: @isherwood The code does throw an error (image does not return) but oddly doesn't blow up the entire page. I can confirm this in the live situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wrong call to get
2. image source is not assigned anywhere, `img src=pictureURL`  is wishful thinking
3. switch does not return a value

> The switch statement evaluates an expression, matching the expression's value to a case clause, and executes statements associated with that case, as well as statements in cases that follow the matching case.

You likely meant to do this

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const pictureParam = urlParams.get('picture')
  document.getElementById("img").src = `https://www.website.com/graphics/image_${pictureParam ===  'ws10m' ? 'ws10m.png' : 't2m.png'}`
})
```

```html
<img src="" id="img" alt="Test" width="1920" height="1080">
```

Alternative for more versions

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const pictureParam = urlParams.get('picture');
  document.getElementById("img").src = `https://www.website.com/graphics/image_${pictureParam ? pictureParam  :  'default.png'}`
})
```

```html
<img src="" id="img" alt="Test" width="1920" height="1080">
```

Comment: Appreciate the guidance here! A follow-up question for this edit, if I have different URL string variables (besides 'ws10m') that can be passed, say 'var1', 'var2', 'varx', is there a recommend way to write the code to handle multiple under `document.getElementById("img").src = pictureParam ===`?

Comment: See updated script. I suggest a default image and then just use the pictureParam if it is there

Comment: I've deployed this and found this code alteration works exactly as desired, thank you for your prompt help. I will accept your answer!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `locationchange` event to detect if the URL has been changed by a button click.

The code is as follows :

```js
const obj = document.getElementById('#IDFromDOM');

function updateImage(){

  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const pictureParam = urlParams.get('picture')

  const pictureUrl = pictureParam === 'ws10m' ? 'https://www.website.com/graphics/image_ws10m.png' : 'https://www.website.com/graphics/image_t2m.png'
  
  obj.src = pictureUrl;
}
window.addEventListener('locationchange', updateImage);
updateImage(); //Fire a first time on page load
```